# In what geographical region is my S3 bucket stored?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created an Amazon Web Services S3 bucket in the past, without specifying the geographic region for it to be stored in. How do I determine which region the bucket is located in?

My reason for asking, is that I am preparing to run some "Amazon Elastic MapReduce" jobs on the data in the bucket, and this service asks me in what region I want the job to run. As it seems reasonable to run the job as close to the data as possible, I would like to know where to data actually is.

The options in Elastic MapReduce are:

- US East (Virginia)
- US West (N. California)
- EU West (Ireland)

I am not if these are the exact same locations available in S3. Anyways, I would like to identify the one that is at least closest to my data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you specified something else, it'll be North America.

If you log in to [Amazon web services](http://aws.amazon.com), and view your usage report, it'll tell you whether it's EU / US or something other.

From reading the Amazon S3 / MapReduce stuff, the regions are different between the two apps, so you probably want to stick to either EU or US (rather than east or west).

Cheers

Comment: Good idea - the usage reports confirms that my data is somewhere in the US.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [GET Location Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html) request. Most probably your bucket is in US.

Comment: With no location constraint set, this command returns nothing: `<LocationConstraint xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"/>`

Comment: According to the docs ...
"When the bucket's region is US East (N. Virginia), Amazon S3 returns an empty string for the bucket's region"

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who comes across this looking for a way to determine the region of a bucket, regardless of whether you're the bucket owner (which is a constraint of [GET bucket location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html)), use [HEAD Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketHEAD.html), e.g.:

```
curl -sI foo.s3.amazonaws.com | awk '/^x-amz-bucket-region:/ { print $2 }'
```

which returns the value of the header `x-amz-bucket-region` for the bucket "foo", in this case:

```
us-east-1
```